# Lab Equipment for Monitoring Sub Zero Temperatures

Tags: temperature

I am doing research on objects frozen with liquid nitrogen then seeing how they thaw.

I need to monitor objects temperatures as they thaw. Ideally getting the variance of the external and internal temperatures.

What strategy or equipment would you recommend to get this data.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please share lab equipment currently available for use. Do you have access the data loggers?

Comment: Ill need that as well, cost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get [thermocouples](http://www.thermometricscorp.com/thermocouple.html) which are rated for cryogenic temperatures. These produce a voltage whcih can be calibrated to temperature and so are faily easy to connect to digiotal or analogue data logging equipment.

They are essentially just a wire so they are easy to embed in things and they can be fitted to various probes and pads for differnt mounting configurations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, do you think I could use something like this on something as small as a pea.

Comment: Possibly, a thermocouple is really just a pair of wires joined at one end so they can potentially be very small.

Comment: Ok, thanks to all for the info, ill do some research and try to come up with a system.